# Not able to access attribute which name begins with a digit

Tags: python, syntax-error, pcap, pyshark

I am using Pyshark to parse a PCAP. There are some object which name begin with digit say `pkt.diameter.3gpp_reporting_reason`. I'm not able to refer to this object, because I get an error "invalid decimal literal".

Any ideas how to retrieve the attribute `pkt.diameter.3gpp_reporting_reason.all_fields`?

[Screenshot of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pcbjj.png)

Comment: When you have code, please create a minimally reproducible example and add that code to your question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't paste code, errors or other text as image. Instead copy-paste the text and make sure to format it correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that names starting with digits aren't valid identifiers in python. While python is reading your code, it things you are entering a number.

To still access the attribute, use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr).

```py
getattr(pkt.diameter, "3gpp_reporting_reason").all_fields
```